# Change order of integration of this triple integral from $dz,dy,dx$ to$ dy,dx,dz$, and all other permutations of $ dy,dx,dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following integral:

$
\text{Volume}(E) = \iiint\limits_E dV \\
= \int_0^{12} \int_0^{6 - x/2} \int_0^{(12 - x - 2y)/3} \, dz \, dy \, dx \\
= ...  \quad \text{(I cheated and did this in WolframAlpha)} \\
= 48
$

I want to compute the same volume of E using $V^{'} =dy,dx,dz$ and haven't had luck.

$
\text{Volume}(E) = \iiint\limits_E dV^{'} \\
= \int_0^{4} \int_0^{-2y+12} \int_0^{(3/2z+6-x/2)} \, dy \, dx \, dz \\
 $

$\neq$  48

I have a plane, $x+2y+3z=12$ with $x$-intercept of $12$, $y=6$, and $z=4$.
So between origin and these points, I have a pyramid.
$(0,0,0)$, $(12,0,0)$, $(0,6,0)$, $(0,0,4)$.

I'm wondering in general what's the formula for converting dz,dy,dx to dy,dx,dz and all permutations of $dx,dy,dz$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct integral is $\int_0^4 \int_0^{\color{red}{-3z+12}}\int_0^{\color{red}{-}3z/2+6-x/2}dydxdz=48$.
[wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB0%20to%204%20%E2%88%AB0%20to%20-3z%2B12%20%E2%88%AB0%20to%20-3z%2F2%2B6-x%2F2%20%20dydxdz)